# $http.get not populating dropdown within directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have this `$http.get` call inside my directive (`myApp.directive('wizard', function ($http) { });`)

```
$http.get('/api/TimeSlotsAPI').then(function(result) {

  if (result.data.length == 0) {
    toggleSteps($scope.currentStepIndex + 4);
  } else {
    $scope.dateTimeSlots = result.data;
    toggleSteps($scope.currentStepIndex + 1);
  }

});
```

The $http.get call is getting called and when I `console.log` the result, I get the expected results, if I console log $scope.dateTimeSlots it has the expected results.

However my dropdown will not populate with the results.

```
<select class="form-control" name="timeSlot" ng-model="user.dateTimeSlot" ng-options="x.timeSlot as x.dateSlot for x in dateTimeSlots" ng-blur="blur22=true" required style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;"></select>
```

What Am I doing wrong here?

Here is a screenshot of the what console.log returns:

[image]

and here is the json response

```
[{"id":1,"dateSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017 - 6:00pm","timeSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017-6:00pm","order":1},{"id":2,"dateSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017 - 6:30pm","timeSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017-6:30pm","order":2},{"id":3,"dateSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017 - 7:00pm","timeSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017-7:00pm","order":3},{"id":4,"dateSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017 - 7:30pm","timeSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017-7:30pm","order":4},{"id":5,"dateSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017 - 8:00pm","timeSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017-8:00pm","order":5},{"id":6,"dateSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017 - 8:30pm","timeSlot":"Monday February 6th, 2017-8:30pm","order":6}]
```

Update, I dont think this has anything to do with the ng-options, if I put the $http.get outside the directive and put it inside the angular.module.controller it works perfectly, my dropdown gets populated, It just does not get populated inside the directive.

Comment: post your json what you have

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: What scope does the directive use: isolate, inherited, or none?

Comment: return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,

        scope: {
            onBeforeStepChange: '&',
            onStepChanging: '&',
            onAfterStepChange: '&',
            user: '=',
        },

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure you're injecting `$scope`?

Comment: Can you post your directive here ?